# Mask a url to file with custom url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site which has a list of URLs to files e.g. https://www.example.com/fileA_02-2021.pdf.

I need to create some sort of custom url that masks the actual url of the file to something like https://www.example.com/file.pdf so that if the original files url is changes to some thing new e.g. https://www.example.com/fileB_03-2021.pdf, then the custom url will always return the wanted file.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated :)

Comment: Then you need a link on your page that points to a bit of code. ___URL stands for Uniform Resource Locator. A URL is nothing more than the address of a given unique resource on the Web___

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm not getting you the right way.

I think you mean that you need to have the same URL for every file while being redirected to the original file when the mask URL clicked.

If this is what you mean, you need to do this using JS and PHP. You need to echo the masked URL in this way in an Anchor tag:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/file.php" data-original="<?php echo $the_file_name; // fileA_02-2021.pdf ?>" class="maskedUrl">Link</a>
```

And then you need to do the rest of the job in JS using jQuery in this way:

```
$('.maskedUrl').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var original_convention = $(this).data('original');
   location.href = "https://www.example.com/" + original_convention;
});
```

Hope this will help you.